# Conditionally install components based in Install Directory, WiX installer

Tags: windows-installer, wix3

I'm creating an installer using WiX Toolset.

I'm using WixUI_InstallDir UI, because i need to choose where the files are going to be installed.

My requirement is user choose to install inside Program Files, some of the files (configs) should go in ProgramData folder, otherwise, it'll be inside the install directory itself,

This is what i've got so far.

```
    <!--Add Components in [ProgramData]/Configs-->
    <DirectoryRef Id="CommonConfigsFolder">
        <Component Id="ServiceConfigAppData" Guid="{1053F925-BEB3-4020-90C5-6EF163326B5E}">
          <Condition>
            <![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR >< "Program Files"]]>
          </Condition>
          <CreateFolder>
            <Permission User="Everyone" FileAllRights="yes"/>
          </CreateFolder>
          <File Id="ServicesConfigFileAppData" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ConfigPath)\Services.cfg"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <!--Add Components in [INSTALLFOLDER]/Configs-->
    <DirectoryRef Id="LocalConfigFolder">
      <Component Id="ServiceConfigLocal" Guid="{B4E52504-C4BF-4C99-88C4-5AF54D49E78A}">
        <Condition>
          <![CDATA[NOT (WIXUI_INSTALLDIR >< "Program Files")]]>
        </Condition>
        <CreateFolder>
          <Permission User="Everyone" FileAllRights="yes"/>
        </CreateFolder>
        <File Id="ServicesConfigFileLocal" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ConfigPath)\Services.cfg"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

But it's always writing the files to install directory, even if i install in program files

I had to define
`<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER"/>` in order to make WixUI_InstallDir work

Comment: Don't install config files. Create them from internal application defaults or instantiate them from read-only file copies installed somewhere safe.

Comment: Yes, i reverted to that idea, after not finding anything